# Fake DNS response

Tags: python, sockets, dns, response, scapy

I wanted to create a fake dns response with scapy and it's just doesn't work... When i sniff the packets in Wireshark it shows me that the packets are correct but Windows just takes the genuine response packet althought...
Can someone tell me how to fix it please?
Thanks

```
import sys
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr
from scapy.all import *
sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e
def f(packet):
    if DNS in packet and DNSQR in packet :
        return True
    return False
while True:
    a=sniff(lfilter=f,count=1)
    ip = a[0].getlayer(IP)
    dns = a[0].getlayer(DNS)
    pkt = Ether(dst = a[0][Ether].src, src = a[0][Ether].dst)/IP(dst=ip.src, src=ip.dst)/UDP(chksum=None, dport=ip.sport,sport=ip.dport)/DNS(qd=a[0][DNS].qd, qdcount=1, ancount=0, nscount=0, arcount=1, ra = 1, qr = 1, id=dns.id, an = (DNSRR(rrname=dns.qd.qname, type= "A" , ttl=3600, rdata="192.168.1.12")))
    pkt.show()
    for i in range(10):
        sendp(pkt)
```

Comment: Maybe the true packets are coming faster than yours? Did you compare both replies and see differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just sniffing packets, if you want to manipulate packets you should send them to a function then forward them to the destination. use prn attribute in Sniff :

```
packets = sniff(filter="port 53" , prn=func , count=1) 
def func(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(UDP) and packet.haslayer(DNS):
         manipulate your DNS packet here then forward it
```

Comment: The "manipulate your DNS packet here then forward it" is exactly what the code does in the `while True`, `sendp` is exactly the function that sends the packets...

Comment: When you sniff a packet and assigns it to a variable it  means you grab the packet's information and send it to the destination after that you'll send a fake one but with prn and sending the packet to a function you grab the origenal and manipulate the original.

Comment: @AliKargar that last comment of yours is wrong: the cases are very similar, except that using `prn` uses the same socket instance, and has improved performances.